# Reason for getting garbage value in C

Tags: c, pointers

I'm running this code and getting some garbage value while printing *ptr. What could be the possible reason and how can I avoid getting that?

```
# include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int test = 1; 
  int *ptr = &test;
  *ptr++ = 10; 
  test++; 
  printf("\nThe value is %d", *ptr);
}
```

Comment: `*ptr++` increments the pointer. So it no longer points to a valid location. Change that to `*ptr = 10;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You moved `ptr` with `ptr++`. Why?

Don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

The statement `*ptr++` increments the pointer which could not be valid for your program.
Rewrite the statement as `*ptr = 10;`